# SqlDataReader behaving differently between projects

Tags: c#, sqldatareader

My project is a Windows Service, and I was having trouble returning values from my database so I separated the bit of code out into a Console Application to make for easier debugging but the code that doesn't work in my Service works in the Console Application.

So in my Service I have this class

```
public class DBHandler
{
    public string ReadSQL(string sql)
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection DBConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=***;Initial Catalog=***;Integrated Security=True;User ID=***;Password=***"))
            {
                DBConnection.Open();
                SqlCommand DBCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, DBConnection);
                SqlDataReader sqlResults = DBCommand.ExecuteReader();
                if (sqlResults.HasRows)
                {
                    while (sqlResults.Read())
                    {
                        return sqlResults.GetString(0);
                    }
                }
                return sqlResults.HasRows.ToString();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
    return e.ToString();
    }
}
```

Which I am using like

```
DBHandler dbHandler = new DBHandler();
WriteToClientStream(clientStream, dbHandler.ReadSQL(string.Format("SELECT PlayerName FROM Player WHERE PlayerName = '{0}'", UserName)) + "\r\n");
```

sqlResults.HasRows returns false, but the same query returns results in SQL Server and the test console application

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ReadSQL(string.Format("SELECT PlayerName FROM Player WHERE PlayerName = '{0}'", "Hex")));
    Console.ReadLine();
}

public static string ReadSQL(string sql)
{
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection DBConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=***;Initial Xatalog=***;Integrated Security=True;User ID=***;Password=***"))
        {
            DBConnection.Open();
            SqlCommand DBCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, DBConnection);
            SqlDataReader sqlResults = DBCommand.ExecuteReader();
            if (sqlResults.HasRows)
            {
                while (sqlResults.Read())
                {
                    return sqlResults.GetString(0);
                }
            }
            return sqlResults.HasRows.ToString();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return e.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you attach a debugger to the service and step through the function? Also a few other questions/problems: You are not returning a `IEnumberable<string>`, are you expecting to return multiple rows from the query? If not you and are only returning the first column why are you using a `SqlDataReader` when you should be using `ExecuteScalar()`? Also returning a string instead of letting the exception bubble up seems like odd design choice to me. How do you tell the difference between a valid result and a error? (same goes for returning the string `"false"` when you have no rows)

Comment: It wont let me attach the debugger to me service process for some reason which is why I split it out into a console application to test it. I had similar problems using ExecuteScalar() which is why I was trying things like SqlDataReader.

ExecuteScalar() works in the console app, but not in the service.

e.ToString() returns

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an obj
ect.
   at GWOService.DBHandler.ReadSQL(String sql)

Comment: Have it print `e.StackTrace` too and get the exact line number the error happens on. Then update the question indicating that you are getting a `NullRefrenceException` and which line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be due to trailing `chars` on the end of the string after encoding the `byte[]` to `string`

after running `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message)` check to make sure there are no null terminators or new lines etc.

Example:

```
System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message).TrimEnd('\0', '\n');
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the problem is easier than you would expect.

How about if you try the same parameter in the Service like you do in the console application?

So change your existing code from:

```
   WriteToClientStream(clientStream, dbHandler.ReadSQL(string.Format(
    "SELECT PlayerName FROM Player WHERE PlayerName = '{0}'", UserName)) + "\r\n");
```

To:

```
WriteToClientStream(clientStream, dbHandler.ReadSQL(string.Format(
"SELECT PlayerName FROM Player WHERE PlayerName = '{0}'", "Hex")));
```

Please try if that works.

If yes, you may have to check your code if you pass the `UserName` correctly.

Comment: So when I change it to "Hex" it works.

UserName is

    `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message)`

And message is

`byte[] message = new byte[4096];`

Which when I output both one after the other look identical?

Comment: Maybe it's also because you append '"\r\n"' at last. just leave this out. ;)
Also you should use parameterized queries. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html